# react native FlatList on scroll combined

Tags: react-native, onscroll

I got a FlatList, this works ok...

```
    <FlatList ...
     onScroll={
        Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
        {
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }
        )
      }
```

now I want to combine above with active onScroll index...

```
    <FlatList ...
      onScroll={onScroll}
```

...

```
  const onScroll = useCallback(
    (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
      const slideSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width;
      const index = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / slideSize;
      const roundIndex = Math.round(index);
      console.log('roundIndex:', roundIndex);

      //how to combine the below?
      Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }], {
        useNativeDriver: false,
      });
    },
    []
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OnEndReached` function of flatlist.

If you use `onScroll` in Flatlist then sometimes its not working for the android, but for iOS it works.